# R, two way table labels

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains gender and marital status represented by 0 and 1. So 1 is female and 0 is male. Married is 1 and unmarried is 0. When I make my two way table in **R** programming I am unable to determine which column and row relates to what data. So my question is how can I label the rows/columns of the table.

Comment: Use dimension names. Tables in R are addressed and names in the same manner as matrices. Generally functions that return tables allow naming, but you need to provide the code.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you label the columns correctly there should be no ambiguity:

```
set.seed(123) # used for reproducibilty
df1 <- data.frame(married=sample(2,100,replace = TRUE)-1, 
                  gender=sample(2,100,replace = TRUE)-1)
head(df1)
#  married gender
#1       0      1
#2       1      0
#3       0      0
#4       1      1
#5       1      0
#6       0      1
table(df1)
#       gender
#married  0  1
#      0 25 28
#      1 25 22
```

If you already have a data.frame and need to provide names to the columns, see `?colnames`.

Comment: table(ACS$Sex, ACS$Married) thats my code im not using a data.frame just basic table function. I assume there is an argument i can use to set the names.

Comment: What is the output of `class(ACS)`?

Comment: This question is not reproducible so I don't see what's the point of posting an answer if you don't really know what the OP has and before getting any clarifications. Also `table` has a `dnn` attribute.

Comment: data.frame is the output.

Comment: Then you can try `table(ACS$Sex,ACS$Married,dnn=list("Sex","Married"))`

Comment: Okay that solves one problem, How do i change the 0 to be not married and 1 be married. Otherwise its hard to read this table without knowing 1 and 0's values

Comment: @cyX For this I suggest that you rename the values in your data.frame: `ACS$Married <- as.factor(ACS$Married); levels(ACS$Married) <- c("not married", "married")` and correspondingly for `ACS$Sex`.

Comment: kk thanks david and Rhertel for the dnn attribute thats pretty much all i wanted.